# $x^4 + x^2 + 1 = 0$ has no solution in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: roots

I need to prove that the equation $x^4 + x^2 + 1 = 0$ has no solution in $\mathbb{R}$.

How would I go about proving this?

Comment: Have you tried factoring the left-hand side?

Answer (score 42):

$x^2$ and $x^4$ are not negative, so
$$1+x^2+x^4\ge1$$
for any real number $x$.

Comment: This is better than my answer. On the bright side, at least my answer will work.

Comment: This is the type of proof I was looking for! It seems obvious after reading your answer, but how would you come up with that in the first place?

Comment: Hard to resist upvoting this answer, ***plus one!***

Comment: @GWAO Just think real numbers with even exponents as nonnegative numbers.

Answer (score 5):

I would solve the equation. Take $y=x^2$. Then the equation is $y^2+y+1=0$. This is quadratic and easy to solve.

Comment: I tried that! It seemed a little too simple to be true haha

Comment: @GWAO the lesson is that sometimes math is as simple as it looks!

Answer (score 4):

Easy!  Since $x^4 \ge 0$ and $x^2 \ge 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, we have $x^4 + x^2 \ge 0$, whence $x^4 + x^2 + 1 > 0$, $\forall x \in \Bbb R$.  No zeroes in $\Bbb R$,  no solution!  ***QED!!!***

Of course, if we allow $x \in \Bbb C$, we have a different story altogether, which is told in a different place.

Hope this helps.  Cheers!

And as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Do you think you could use a few more exclamation points in there?  ;)

Comment: No such thing as too many exclamations. Helps get your point across. (!!!)

Comment: @Dasherman:  I couldn't agree more ***!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***

Comment: @augurar:  try 'em, you'll like 'em . . . Hell!  You'll ***Love*** 'em ***!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***

Comment: And a Jovial Yule Season to All and Sundry ***!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*** ***Ho ho ho!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!***